# Obtain directory of a file in C code

Tags: c, directory-structure

This question may be a bit naive, but I'm wondering if it's possible to obtain the directory part of a filename in C code. For instance, say I have the following Linux file:

/home/user/Documents/Work/report.txt

and I want to obtain the string "/home/user/Documents/Work/"

Are there any C functions to do such a thing? Also, even though I gave a Linux file as an example, I'd like to be able to obtain the directory listing of a file on any OS.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at [`strrchr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strrchr.html).

Comment: It looks like strrchr() would be more useful to locate the basename of a file rather than its directory. How would you use it to find the directory?

Comment: @Decave You NUL-terminate the string at the position returned by `strrchr()`. But really, use the right tool for the task - `dirname()`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the [`dirname()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/dirname.html) function is for:

```
char path[] = "/var/www/index.html";
char *dirn = dirname(path);
printf("Dirname: %s\n", dirn);
```

Comment: Note: `dirname()` (even though it does what OP wants) is not described by the C Standard.

Comment: @pmg I believe it's POSIX, though?

Comment: @H2CO3: yes, it's described by POSIX as in the link you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Use `strrchr()` and replace the last separator character with a `'\0'`

```
#define PATH_SEPARATOR_CHAR '/'
char text[10000] = "/home/user/Documents/Work/report.txt";
char *last = strrchr(text, PATH_SEPARATOR_CHAR);
if (last) {
    *last = 0;
    printf("path is '%s'\n", text);
} else {
    printf("Invalid text\n");
}
```